# How to restore apache configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have placed .htaccess file in my server's root folder with following content:

```
Redirect 303 /index.html http://mysite.com/index.php
```

to redirect my index.html to index.php.

Now some of the php files are not displaying, instead a blank page.

I want to restore all the changes done by .htaccess file.

Does anyone have any idea how to get out of this problem or how to restore all the changes done by .htaccess file?

Comment: .htaccess files do not make any changes to your php files.

Comment: i don' see how the above would effect other files, is there anything else in the .htaccess file ?

Comment: does .htaccess file do change any server configuration? or changes in server configuration files?

Comment: no my .htaccess file contains only one line i.e. 'Redirect 303 /index.html http://mysite.com/index.php '

Comment: what server configuration files are you talking about ?

Comment: httpd.conf file or whatever files that can possibly be changed by .htaccess

Comment: .htaccess file does not change other files. A blank page with a php file is usually because there is an error and you don't have display errors on, so either turn hem on or check the php error log -this has nothing to do with your .htaccess  settings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6305/discussion-between-manoj-nakum-and-dagon)

Comment: you already posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697861/what-does-htaccess-do-exactly don't post it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing .htacces file would not affect your server configuration,

second, place (restore) your old working .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

rename

- .htaccess

to

- .htaccess_yyyymmdd

**note:** this is also a "backup" possibility before you apply new changes.

Comment: now i have removed .htaccess file from my server, but still .php files are not getting displayed, does .htaccess file do any changes in server configuration files?

Comment: do you know how to come out of this problem? because now i have removed .htaccess file from the server but still my php files are not getting displayed

Comment: do you have html output in your php file? if it not outputted, it will not be displayed... note: it would help if you would post your index.php file or another one thatyou like to "display".

Comment: when i view the source of that file, there is nothing to display, means it gives blank html output